# Finding a path between 2 points passing through N points

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

Given a graph/plane with N points each at a given coordinate how could I find a path between 2 points via N other points where each point is weighted on how likely it is to be passed through.

- Distances between points can be calculated
- Path must be less than a given distance

Apologies if the vocabulary isn't quite right or I've posted this in the wrong place

Comment: Are you trying to solve some special case of [TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement.  Please edit the question to clarify what you are asking.  What does "where each point is weighted on how likely it is to be passed through" mean?  Am I allowed to select the path however I like?  Is the path selected randomly?  Does the path have to go through exactly N other points, or can it go through more or less?  What are the inputs to the algorithm, and what are the desired outputs?  What approaches have you already considered, and why did you reject them?  Have you tried to solve this problem on your own?

Comment: My problem is I want to find a route between 2 points on a map while passing though any given number points so long as the route length is less than some arbitrary length. Each point would be weighted so that the point is more likely/less to be included in the route.